# .Net Core 2.0 build under cygwin

Tags: .net-core-2.0

I'm .NET Core begginer, I have several projects dependent on proj_core

> proj1
> proj2
> ...
> ...
> proj_core

and a simple file build.sh run under cygwin:

```
build_one_proj()
{
    ...
    dotnet build --configuration Debug  --output "../bin" --framework $NETCOREVER
    ...
}

build_one_proj proj1
build_one_proj proj2
...
```

It performs so different after upgrade to .NET Core 2.0 (same build.sh):

> .NET Core 1.1: short build time (average time < 20 seconds), console output show only modified projects be build.
>
> .NET Core 2.0: long build time (average time > 60 seconds), assording to output I guess all projects be build, especially proj_core be build repeatedly.

I read docs about build option and googled, but still have no clue. Could someone please enlighten me, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you previously used `project.json` to build .NET Core 1.0/1.1 apps, then the move to csproj / MSBuild tooling for 2.0 will be noticeable.

Note that there are a few changes happening at the moment in the SDK (!, not runtime) in the 2.1 and 2.2 versions.

There are two changes in the 2.0:

1. The build performs an implicit restore. This will update the obj\project.assets.json file and download missing nuget packages if needed. If you switch between an IDE in windows and linux-based tools that use different paths, this may be slower. Use the `--no-restore` to not do this.
2. ASP.NET Core 2.0 introduces the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage, adding significant number of NuGet packages and DLLs to the build that you could reference from the app. MSBuild spends a lot of time searching the paths of these DLLs for additional assets (debug symbols, additional DLLs, resource satellite assemblies). This will be removed in the 2.2 tooling since all known assets are known beforehand.

Also, file globbing (discovering files in the project) is faster in the 2.1 CLI than in 2.0. But when there is a really large directory (e.g. `node_modules`) that isn't needed, it is better to exclude it. ASP.NET Core will exclude a `node_modules` folder in the project root level, but if there is another one in a different location or the project isn't ASP.NET Core, it may be faster to set:

```
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);path\to\node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
```

MSBuild recognises this pattern and doesn't even consider enumerating the contents of this directory.

You are also passing an "output" parameter. Note that this causes some additional build time when a project is called with different parameters for this, e.g. via IDEs or when built as referenced project if this parameter is not used.

I recommend setting `<OutputPath>path\to\dir\</OutputPath>` in a `PropertyGroup` in the csproj files or creating a `Directory.Build.props` file in your solution directory setting it to e.g. `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\` to make sure that all builds see the same value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My project isn't ASP.NET Core and has no node_modules in project folder. Do I still need to add <DefaultItemExcludes> in *.csproj? If so, what is node_modules path?

Comment: No. But if you want more assistance, you have to be more specific in the sdk versions you switched from/to and maybe reproduce it in an example solution.